# Application design for when a database is temporarily disconnected?

Tags: c#, architecture, .net-4.0

Here is the problem:

- Incoming data from source
- Your program that process that data

  - Written in C# and targeting **.NET 4.0**
- Output database not associated with source
- Output database may be disconnected temporarily

  - Disconnection time is between 0 and 2 hours
  - Still receiving data from source while disconnected

What would be the right pattern to follow when you have this situation? Is this too vague or situation specific?

Comment: Use a persistent queue. Incoming into queue, pop from queue when successful send to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache it using a queue on the server side.
Remove the data off the queue once the data is dumped into DB.